# Divisor Function

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

Divisor Function d(N) is the number of divisors of N less than or equal to N.
Ex. d(1)=1,d(2)=2,d(10)=4...so on....

I had a question that says to compute answer to function Z(N)=d(1)+d(2)+d(3)....d(N)
After some thinking I figured out Z(N)= N+(N/2)+(N/3)....+1 .

But I got stuck here because if I take N common...
Z(N)=N(1+(1/2)+(1/3).....(1/N))
and Z(N)~~N*ln(N+.52771)....
But I want accurate answer.

Can somebody give a elegant answer since N can be very large...

Comment: The summatory function for the divisor function is discussed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function --- maybe you could have a look at that, and then report back here on what you found.

Comment: Thanks alot, I googled that too...but didn't find this post...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Anyway, another site you might find helpful is http://oeis.org/A006218

Answer (score 1):

Terence Tao has an archive "What's new", and there is a nice article on the divisor function
$$
d(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} 1
$$
and the sum 
$$
\sum_{n\le x}d(n)=\sum_{d\le x}\sum_{n\le x,\; d\mid n}1=\sum_{d\le x}\left(\frac{x}{d}+O(1)\right)=x\log x+O(x),
$$
and better estimates - if you want an elegant answer. 
The archive can be found here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/divisor-function/.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of looking at $N/2, N/3, N/4$, all the way to $N$, you could save yourself some time by considering that $a<b$ in $ab$, you don't have to count $b$ separately.

For example, suppose you want to look at the sum of divisors to $120$.  So, if we look for instances of $a \ne b$ in $ab$, we count only the lesser divisor, and we count the squares just once.

For example, removing the first 9 multiples of 9, where 9 is the larger divisor, gives just $120/9-9=4$, which are $90, 99, 108, 117$  The larger divisors here are $10, 11, 12, 13$.  For $10$, we have $120/10-10 = 2$, we count $110, 120$.

So, we get $120/1-1 = 119$, and $120/2-2 = 58$ and $120/3-3= 37$ and $120/4-4 = 26$, and $120/5-5 = 19$, and $120/6-6 = 14$, and $120/7-7 = 10$, and $120/8-8 = 7$, and $120/9-9=4$, and $120/10-10 = 2$, and $120/11-11 < 0$.

We add $119+58+37+26+19+14+10+7+4+2 = 296$ pairs of the form $ab, a<b$, and $10$ squares, so the total number of divisors is $296+296+10 = 602$.